# Android device if not support for multitouches is there any way to detect multi touches?

Tags: android, multi-touch

I am new to android and I just want to know is there any way to (tricky way) detect multi-touches on devices which not support multi touches. I just want to is it possible or not.

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, these days even worst phones supports multi touch. Even if you are curious, you can tweek with this code. https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

Comment: Because I need to detect more than 2 touches. but actually my mobile support for 2 points. (I tested it with 'MultiTouchTester') and for now my app correctly detect single touch and two points touches..

Answer (score 0):

```
relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getPointerCount() > 1){
                    //more than 1 touch detected
                }else{
                    //less than  or equal to 1 touch
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I could not find any direct method, but using this trick you can check how many touch pointers are active on the device.

`motionEvent.getPointerCount()` returns the number of active touch recorded by the sensor.

you can read more about [multi touch](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html) and [pointers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId(int)).